# How to speed up port scanner C#?

Tags: c#

I created very simple scanner that will take ip range, get random ip within this range and check if particular port is opened. I use TcpClient

```
string PORT_CHECK(string IPorNAME, int port)
{
    TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
    tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;
    tcpClient.SendTimeout = 10000;
    try
    {
        tcpClient.Connect(IPorNAME, port);
        return IPorNAME + " : OPEN";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return IPorNAME + " : CLOSED";
    }
}
```

I use threadpool

```
void main()
{
    while (stopper == false)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(bGround));
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
}
```

It checks about 10 ips per second, for example a scanner like VNC achieves a speed of about 500 per second, where this major difference comes from, and what to do to speed up my code?

Comment: You've set `ReceiveTimeout` and `SendTimeout` both to `10000`ms (10 seconds). Which means it will wait 10 seconds until it decides it's not there, I'd suggest lowering this number greatly, somewhere around one second (`1000`) or lower.

Comment: @AlphaDelta - you should promote this as an answer.

Comment: @STLDeveloper There we go!

Comment: I have tried 1000, also 3000, it is slightly faster but I get less IPs with open ports (I mean really slightly faster)

Comment: I don't get your threadpool queue, what is `bGround`?

Answer (score 2):

You've set `ReceiveTimeout` and `SendTimeout` both to `10000`ms (10 seconds). Which means it will wait 10 seconds until it decides it's not there, I'd suggest lowering this number greatly, somewhere around one second (`1000`) or lower.

Comment: No, It's not that, I tried with 1000 ms and with 100 ms and I get the same results...

Comment: I don't get it. How the send/receive timeouts could affect this ? Here the socket is simply connected, nothing is being sent or received.